# Как подобное реализуется? html

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать подобное? Cоответственно если текста меньше, то и линии должны быть длиннее

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d0h3pL6b/

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.black {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.black::after {
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.black span {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="black"><span>Нужно больше текста!!!</span>
</div>
```